# Except block always being thrown even after going through the try block and rest of the program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, try-catch

I check to see if input can be changed into an integer if it can't it starts back from the beginning of UI(). I followed it through pycharm's debugger and it will pass the try, but when I try using 4 to exit.It will go through to the end, and then go back up to the except block.

I think the parts I commented after are the only relevant parts. Thanks for any help.

```
    def UI():
    global exitBool
    global newBool

    if not TV.tvList:
       tv = TurnOnTV()
    if TV.tvList:
        l = list(TV.tvList.keys())
        tv = TV.tvList.get(l[0])

    print("1)change channel\n2)change volume\n3)Turn on another TV\n4)Exit\n5)Choose TV")   #print accepted answers

    choice = input()

    try:
        choice = int(choice)                #try block and exception block
    except:
        print("\nInvalid Choice\n")
        UI()

    choice = int(choice)

    if choice == 1:
        if tv:
            tv.changechannel(input("enter channel: "))
        else:
            print('sorry no tvs are available\n')
    elif choice == 2:
        if tv:
            tv.changevolume(input("Enter in volume: "))
        else:
            print('Sorry no Tvs available')

    elif choice == 3:
        TurnOnTV()
    elif choice == 4:
        exitBool = True     # exit bool to exit main loop
    elif choice == 5:
       tv = ChooseTV(input("Enter in TV name: "))
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice")

    if tv:
        tv.display()

def Main():
    while exitBool == False:       #Main Loop
        UI()
```

Comment: This is a hell. You (probably accidently) use recursion and global variables. You should avoid this, unless you really know, what's going on there. Try one while loop for choice input and another for main loop. Also use return values and break instead of global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you catch the error and print "invalid choice" you must not call UI() again. That way you are making a recursive call, and when the inner UI() terminates the code goes on on the outer one.

Use a "while" statement to repeat a block of code until the user makes a valid choice.